# Sap Bo How to plot time on line graph start with 23

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, linegraph

I have time column but i want to plot chart starting with 23 and then 0 & 1 and on

Changing min valu to 23 starts the chart from 23 but next valu would be 22 21 20

You cannot add time into x axis is the limitation. Pl help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a help site for programmers and programming questions. For general usage, please choose another one like https://superuser.com or https://answers.sap.com

Comment: [BusinessObjects Board](https://bobj-board.org/) is another good resource for this type of question.